# How to create List/Detail view with reach/router

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

Since `reach/router` [doesn't support optional params](https://github.com/reach/router/blob/e8325ae7a2d7be0a4e1de266ee15929f85fc2d94/website/src/markdown/pages/credits.md#trade-offs-mostly-compared-to-react-router), how would you go about creating a view like this?

```
┌────────────────┐┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌────────────┐ ││                                                │
│ │   Book 1   │ ││  Book 2                                        │
│ └────────────┘ ││  Name: Unknown knowns                          │
│ ┌────────────┐ ││  Author: Donald                                │
│ │ √ Book 2   │ ││  Year: 2001                                    │
│ └────────────┘ ││  ISBN: 666                                     │
│ ┌────────────┐ ││                                                │
│ │   Book 3   │ ││                                                │
│ └────────────┘ ││                                                │
│ ┌────────────┐ ││                                                │
│ │   Book 4   │ ││                                                │
│ └────────────┘ ││                                                │
│ ┌────────────┐ ││                                                │
│ │   Book 5   │ ││                                                │
│ └────────────┘ ││                                                │
└────────────────┘└────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

On the left there is a list of `Books` that should be rendered either:

- at `/books`
- at `/books/:isbn`

On the right the box shows `Detail`s of a book if at `/books/:isbn` and it's shows an empty box if at `/books`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. This can be done with [Embedded Routers](https://reach.tech/router/example/embedded-routers) and [Wildcards](https://reach.tech/router/api/Match) like:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Books path='/books/*' />
    <Router>
  );
}

function Books() {
  return (
    // ... left-side list here
    <Router>
      <BookDetail path=':isbn' />
    <Router>
  );
}
```